# ios 14.1 Promise.resolve().then() run faster then async invoke

Tags: javascript, ios, promise, jscontext

```js
const resolve = Promise.resolve()
function run() {
  try {
    try {
      
    console.log(1)
    resolve.then(() => {
      console.log(resolve, 2)
    })
    console.log(3)
    } finally {
      console.log(4)
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
  console.log('return')
}
run()
```

in ios 14.1, the result is:

```js
1
3
2
4
return
```

but in ios 16.x, the result is:

```js
1
3
4
return
2
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNauE.png)

Why is this happening?

What is the root cause of the problem and how to solve it